# Does PDB file contain data structures?

Tags: windows, pdb-files

I'm [reading this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/symbol-files?redirectedfrom=MSDN), it says PDB contains `type data`. Does it mean it contains C structure information?

I couldn't find such thing in https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-pdb. It seems like only the type name is available, but no C structure or C++ class definition.

Am I wrong?

Comment: pdb can containing data type information.

Comment: @RbMm Only the name of the structure, but no details, am I right?

Comment: no, full details. if `PDB_STREAM_TPI` stream exist

Comment: are you have more detailed question/problem ? in any case, if type info exist in pdb - possible based on it reconstruct all structures as is. not only names. debuggers of course use this, when show structures and it values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, type information can be included in PDBs. The WinDbg command to display types is `dt`. Microsoft provides some of their type definitions for download if you use `.symfix`. Since `ntdll` is loaded into every process, it's quite simple to demonstrate.

A simple example is a list entry of a doubly linked list, consisting of a forward and backward link:

```
1:001> dt nt!_LIST_ENTRY
ntdll!_LIST_ENTRY
   +0x000 Flink            : Ptr64 _LIST_ENTRY
   +0x008 Blink            : Ptr64 _LIST_ENTRY
```

or a Unicode string:

```
1:001> dt _UNICODE_STRING
ntdll!_UNICODE_STRING
   +0x000 Length           : Uint2B
   +0x002 MaximumLength    : Uint2B
   +0x008 Buffer           : Ptr64 Wchar
```

or a critical section:

```
1:001> dt _RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION
ntdll!_RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION
   +0x000 DebugInfo        : Ptr64 _RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION_DEBUG
   +0x008 LockCount        : Int4B
   +0x00c RecursionCount   : Int4B
   +0x010 OwningThread     : Ptr64 Void
   +0x018 LockSemaphore    : Ptr64 Void
   +0x020 SpinCount        : Uint8B
```